# Reactjs - data flow

Tags: reactjs, state

I have a general question about where to load data in Reactjs.

The main component is called App. Then the App returns 3 components: Header, Body, and Footer. Now within Body, there is a Tab component, which is further subdivided into a few components including a component called "grids".

Now I want my data (after being filtered) displayed in Grids.

Please correct me if I'm doing it wrong but my thinking is:

1. Load data in the main component App as state:
2. Pass it to Body with:

   ```
   <Body data={this.state.data} />
   ```
3. In the Body component, pass it further as:

   ```
   <Tabs data={this.props.data} />
   ```
4. In the Tabs component, pass it further as:

   ```
   <Grids data={this.props.data} />
   ```
5. In Grids, write all the methods to filter data and display/return it accordingly.

Is this correct?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The flow you've outlined is correct. An alternate approach is to use [context](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/context.html): Anything set into context of one component is available to every descendent of that component, without setting props of intermediate components.

[Context comes with a warning though](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/context.html#when-not-to-use-context):

> Using context will make your code harder to understand because it
>   makes the data flow less clear. It is similar to using global
>   variables to pass state through your application.

BTW, for managing data, I'd use something like Flux or Redux. Managing data directly within React components quickly becomes a pain in a** as application grows. Flux/Redux, on the other hand, scale very well.

Comment: Thank you for downvote, care to explain why you disagree?

Comment: Yeah. I have been looking at Redux but still have not got my head around it.